# index.html [welcome file] gives HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

[please see my project structure here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPCOR.png)I am using Spring MVC here is my code.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

when I hit run the project on server I got below error .

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

as per the concept if we do not specify the welcome list tag then automatically index.html  file will be searched.but in my case it is not working however it is working if I change the extension to .jsp.

If any one knows the answer please help me .

Note: I dont want to change the url mapping. I know there are alternatives but I want to know why this is happening and not showing me the result

Comment: can you please show the folder structure of your project??

Comment: I have added image in image description ..please look into that

Comment: in top i have added my project structure image , Ignore the error in web.xml .@RajkumarMamidiChettu-MT

Comment: try with placing index.html under the src/main/resources/static directory i.e. create static folder inside resources folder and add index.html file inside this folder.